# migrate iPhone project to iPad

Tags: ipad

I hope to migrate one project from iPhone to iPad.
My way is to copy all project files to a new path, then open the project in new directory and change the bundle identifier and provisioning profile.

I know I need to do some adjustment for UIViews etc in Interface Builder. There is no problem for me.

But I remember when create a new project, there are options for 'iphone, ipad and universal'.

Is there an environment parameter/option in existed project that I can change from iPhone to iPad? and inform XCode or Interface Builder that it is the project which has been migrated from iPhone to iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me it would be simpler to create a new empty iPad app and import your files into it, then make changes from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert yet but I do recall seeing a WWDC video on migrating app from iphone to ipad.  You may want to check that out.